# Working with Lists as Pandas cell elements

Tags: python, pandas, list

I am working with pandas dataframes where some of the columns have individual lists as cell elements. I want to conditionally select elements in each of the cell in one column and read the corresponding elements in lists with same index in the other column (and then print as another column). I am struggling how to do it. To explain the problem with example:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3.4 | 5.7 | [1,4,2] | [2.5,3.4,1.2] |
| 1 | 4 | 1.7 | [7,4,5,2] | [12.15,1.2,34.2,67.2] |

I want to put condition on lists in column C (e.g. selecting values > 3 ) and read corresponding elements in column D, to print them in column E. This should give me something like this:

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3.4 | 5.7 | [1,4,2] | [2.5,3.4,1.2] | [3.4] |
| 1 | 4 | 1.7 | [7,4,5,2] | [12.15,1.2,34.2,67.2] | [12.15,1.2,34.2] |

Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List comprehension is your friend - here are zipped columns, and then in nested list comprehension filtered zipped lists:

```
df['E'] = [[b for a, b in zip(x, y) if a > 3] for x, y in zip(df['C'], df['D'])]
print (df)
     A    B             C                         D                   E
0  3.4  5.7     [1, 4, 2]           [2.5, 3.4, 1.2]               [3.4]
1  4.0  1.7  [7, 4, 5, 2]  [12.15, 1.2, 34.2, 67.2]  [12.15, 1.2, 34.2]
```

Or you can use boolean indexing with convert lists to numpy arrays:

```
df['E'] = [list(np.array(y)[np.array(x) > 3]) for x, y in zip(df['C'], df['D'])]
print (df)
     A    B             C                         D                   E
0  3.4  5.7     [1, 4, 2]           [2.5, 3.4, 1.2]               [3.4]
1  4.0  1.7  [7, 4, 5, 2]  [12.15, 1.2, 34.2, 67.2]  [12.15, 1.2, 34.2]
```